# Starting appium in Screen using systemd

Tags: systemd

I'm facing an issue with `systemctl`, where I am not able to start `appium` tool via `systemctl` upon startup on my server.

This is the `systemctl` service I wrote, and I would expect it to be able to start the `appium` tool inside a screen instance within my machine and detach from it, while leaving it running (hence the `-dmS` flags).

```
[Unit]
Description=Start appium 


[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart="screen -dmS appium appium"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When the service is started, I see an error on the service logs that it can't find `appium` in my system. However, if I try to execute it via terminal (`$ screen -dmS appium appium`), I am able to run it fine.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use the full path to the executables e.g. `/bin/scrren` and `/bin/appium`

Comment: @Raffa still getting a similar error `Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/screen -dm /usr/local/bin/appium: No such file or directory`. Verified all paths are correct (did a `whereis appium` and `whereis screen` to double check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** `systemd` runs processes in its own "subshell" which it keeps running once the invocation is completed, like a sort of "`screen` instance".

Therefore, the solution became much simpler than what I was making it out to be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start appium 


[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=appium

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Passing in `appium` command straight away worked as a charm.
If multiple versions are installed, the command `avm use $(VERSION)` can also be used (eg `avm use 1.7.2` for appium `1.7.2`).